# how can I store the data read from the file as a string in an array in c programming?

Tags: c, arrays, file

how can I store the data read from the file as a string in an array in c programming? I think there are some mistakes.

```
int main(){
    FILE *file;  
    char name, character[30]; 
    char x;
    printf("Please enter a file name: ");
    scanf_s("%s", &name);
    if(file !=fopen(&name,"r")){
        printf("File could not be opened.");
    }
    file=fopen(&name,"r");
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        do{
            x=fscanf(file, "%s", &character[i]);
            if(x!=EOF)
                printf("%s\n",&character[i]);
        }
        while(x!=EOF);
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: [mcve], [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Firstly, write the problem as a summary in the title. Then  write the code using the code block section

Comment: I count at least 8 mistakes... didn't your compiler produce *any* warnings at all?

Comment: No, it can run.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have a number of mistakes. The major problem is that you don't reserve memory for the strings. As far as I can see you are trying to read (at most) 30 strings from the file. So you need to do:

```
char name, character[30][128];
```

This will give you memory for 30 strings with maximum length 128 per string.

Another issue is this code

```
if(file !=fopen(&name,"r")){
    printf("File could not be opened.");
}
file=fopen(&name,"r");
```

Here you open the file twice and do some strange compare with an uninitialized variable. Instead do:

```
file=fopen(&name,"r");
if(!file){
    printf("File could not be opened.");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  it can run.